# How to declare variable number of template arguments?

Tags: c++, templates, boost

For example, this is the declaration of `boost::tuple`

```
// - tuple forward declaration -----------------------------------------------
template <
  class T0 = null_type, class T1 = null_type, class T2 = null_type,
  class T3 = null_type, class T4 = null_type, class T5 = null_type,
  class T6 = null_type, class T7 = null_type, class T8 = null_type,
  class T9 = null_type>
class tuple;
```

As expected, I get the following error if I try to use more number of arguments

```
$ g++ vec.cc 
vec.cc: In function 'int main()':
vec.cc:6: error: wrong number of template arguments (12, should be 10)
/usr/include/boost/tuple/detail/tuple_basic.hpp:75: error: provided for 'template<class T0, class T1, class T2, class T3, class T4, class T5, class T6, class T7, class T8, class T9> class boost::tuples::tuple'
vec.cc:6: error: template argument 1 is invalid
vec.cc:6: error: template argument 2 is invalid
vec.cc:6: error: invalid type in declaration before ';' token
$
```

Is there a way to declare the class so that it accepts any number of template arguments?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11#Variadic_templates

Comment: Do you mean such that it behaves like a c++11 std::tuple?

Comment: @juanchopanza: ... like a c++11 tuple in a system that supports variadic templates you mean? VS 2011 for example does not support variadic templates and I *think* that tuple supports infinite types as long as infinite is not greater than 5.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas good question. The standard says tuple should support any number of arguments, and the header is template <class... Types> class tuple. So I guess I mean an std::tuple according to the c++11 standard.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

C++11 supports [variadic templates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_template). These allow you to write:

```
template<typename ...Args>
class tuple
{
    // ...
};
```

However, there is no simple way to iterate over the arguments of a variadic template. See the linked article for several workarounds for this problem.

Comment: You could always convert the variadic parameter pack to an MPL sequence if you wish to iterate over it.